# Can I pay my employees salaries based on a project but not as a fixed salary

Tags: salary

Can I pay my employees salaries based on a project but not as a fixed salary?
The reason for this is because the company does not pay invoices per month, but only on the jobs completion. So employees must also work and complete their jobs.

Will this be fair as it will not affect their rates at all?

Comment: Please dont abuse the shift/caplock key.

Comment: Legal question and terrible formatting.  Voting to close.

Comment: Needs a location at minimum to even attempt to answer this but note that A) it's probably illegal, and B) it's a terrible idea.

Comment: @Lilienthal it is completely legal to do so. You are simply replaceing hours with products. The only Problem I see with it is that you Need to Change hours billed per product every time instead of a fixed hours per month. Which can be administrive pain also how would you calculate vacations is going to be an issue

Comment: @RaoulMensink Depends on the timeframe and whether the employees are contractors. Actual employees need to be paid for their hours worked within X amount of time (2 weeks in most US states IIRC). I believe OP is proposing not paying people for months at a time and only on completion of the project. If he's talking about short jobs then he wants contractors not employees.

Comment: "Will this be fair as it will not affect their rates at all?" - No. What you're essentially employing them as is as contractors. These rates will have to be 2.5 to 3 times higher to attract people for this volatile a position.

Answer (score 5):

You can pay employees any way you want (within the bounds of local laws), the hard part is getting employees who would agree to such a thing. Most people do not want to be worrying about getting paid, they want a steady, dependable income. And it's usually up to the employer to provide it and make sure they keep the work flowing so that they can, not the staff.

My suggestion would be to use consultants, because that is often how their billing is done.

Comment: Good Afternoon, Kindly note that I appreciate your feedback in this regard and note that I am actually acting on behalf of another employer who needs me to revise the current contract on payment terms to this new changes. I know its fair but needed to have side of support from other professionals, I will revise the contracts accordingly and inform all affected parties with all changes.

Comment: To iterate on that: If you want your employees to accept that uncertainty that comes with such a pay structure, you'll have to prepare to pay well above market rate.

Comment: @Magisch or no employees at all

Comment: @Magisch: Not above the market rate. But at the market rate for contractors, not the market rate for employees. IMHO 150 days contracting should pay the same or more as one year employment to take care of the risks. On the other hand, it seems that this company wants to do this because they don't have money to pay employees. Big, big red flag.